# Creating a BMI Ideal Weight calculator (Running into some errors)

Tags: netbeans

I am creating a BMI Ideal Weight calculator where the user is prompted to input data or there information into the textboxes, such as their name, height, weight (the weight can be in metric aka kgs or in imperial aka pounds) and the height can either be in metres or in feet. I also am using a radiobutton, two different ones to distinguish between genders (male or female) because males and females have different BMIs. The information and formulas I'm supposed to refer to is in the photo below, but my problem is so far when I am coding it and I'm just testing out for the male radio button because I completed it, nothing is outputting into my jLabel aka lblOutput... 
Here is a quick rundown of what I want:
1)User is prompted to click on gender (radiobutton)
2)User is then needed to fill in the information
3)Supposed to output BMI and telling the person if it's normal, underweight, etc.
Here is the code (So far what I have):

```
    String name = txt1.getText();
    double Metric = Double.parseDouble(txt2.getText());
    double Imperial = Double.parseDouble(txt2.getText());

    double metres = Double.parseDouble(txt3.getText());

    double inches = Double.parseDouble(txt4.getText());
    double kgs = Double.parseDouble(txt5.getText());
    double pounds = Double.parseDouble(txt5.getText());
    double weight;
    double weight2;
    int m = 1;
    int i =2;
    int me =3;
    int in=4;

    if (rdbMale.isSelected()) {
    if (Metric==m) {
      //inches = System.null(); //need to learn how to make it null or dissapear if user inputs for metric instead of imperial
    weight = metres/Math.pow(kgs, 2);
    lblOutput.setText("Your name is " + name + " and your ideal weight in kgs is " + String.format("%.2f", weight));
    }
    } else if (Imperial==i) {
    weight2 = inches/Math.pow(pounds, 2)*703;
    lblOutput.setText("Your name is " + name + " and your ideal weight in pounds is " + String.format("%.2f", weight2));
    }              

   // some codes are unneccessary like the int me, or the int in i used them so i can distinguish between which one the user wants to chose from either 3 for metres or 4 for inches, pls ignore that
   //I basically just want this to work and I don't know how to get it to work
```

Comment: Having trouble uploading photo of criteria and the JFrame design sorry

Comment: By the way, there is no error when running the program it's just not outputting on my jLabel.

Comment: "what I want"? this isn't a code writing service. This looks like homework and at this stage you should have covered rudimentary debugging.